# Cisco ASA 5505 No LAN access through VPN

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

I have been fighting with this ASA 5505 for a days now. I am verly new to networking and need support by the community! I have completely configured the CISCO 5505 allowing me to browse the internet when connected via VPN. But i am not able to access anything on the LAN side (my remote resources). When connected via VPN (Cisco VPN CLient) i'd like to access de firewall as well using ADAM or SSH.

This is my Configuration:

```
CiscoASA(config)# show run
: Saved
:
ASA Version 9.0(1)
!
hostname CiscoASA
enable password s/ffffuuuuuuuuu encrypted
passwd ffffuuuuuuuuu encrypted
names
ip local pool VPN_IP_POOL 10.0.3.80-10.0.3.90 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.2.254 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address XX.XX.XX.XX 255.255.255.0
!
ftp mode passive
dns domain-lookup outside
dns domain-lookup inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server XX.XX.XX.XX
 name-server XX.XX.XX.XX
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.2.0_24
 subnet 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
object network NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.3.80_28
 subnet 10.0.3.80 255.255.255.240
object network obj-vpnpool
access-list Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN_splitTunnelAcl standard permit 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0
pager lines 24
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any outside
icmp permit any inside
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (inside,outside) source static NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.2.0_24 NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.2.0_24 destination static NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.3.80_28 NETWORK_OBJ_10.0.3.80_28 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 XX.XX.XX.XX 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication serial console LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication http console LOCAL
http server enable
http 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 10.0.3.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto isakmp nat-traversal 30
crypto ikev1 enable outside
crypto ikev1 policy 10
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 20
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 40
 authentication crack
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 50
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 60
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-192
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 70
 authentication crack
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 80
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 90
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 100
 authentication crack
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 110
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 120
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 130
 authentication crack
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 140
 authentication rsa-sig
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 150
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
telnet timeout 5
ssh 10.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 10.0.3.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 60
console timeout 0

dhcpd auto_config outside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 213.132.202.192 source outside
ntp server 72.251.252.11 source outside
ntp server 131.211.8.244 source outside
group-policy Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN internal
group-policy Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN attributes
 dns-server value XX.XX.XX.XX XX.XX.XX.XX
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN_splitTunnelAcl
username admin password ffffuuuuuuuuu encrypted privilege 15
username USERNAME password ffffuuuuuuuuu encrypted privilege 0
username USERNAME attributes
 vpn-group-policy Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN
tunnel-group Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN type remote-access
tunnel-group Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN general-attributes
 address-pool VPN_IP_POOL
 default-group-policy Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN
tunnel-group Default_Tunnel_Group_Name_VPN ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *****
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:161376d95d28d1e4085c029b0ae9e273
: end
CiscoASA(config)#
```

Please make sure in you examples you use the new configuration style for NAT. This will help me a lot.

Comment: Why don't people use the ASDM?

Comment: Even with ASDM I could not get it working! therefore this post. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the virtual networt adapter of Cisco VPN-Clients captures all data packets and sends them through the VPN-Connection, even if the destination IP-address is in local LAN.

You can try to activate "Allow Local LAN Access" in the "Transport" pane of the connection properties. If it does not work, you will have to configure split routing on the ASA.